# window.blur() does not work(please test it)

Tags: javascript, window

For a sandwich, there is a piece of bread at the ***bottom***.

I've tested window.blur() in

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_blur

Please test the code in the above link.

But it seems it does not work.
The new window does not go to the ***bottom***.
It appears on the ***top*** since it was created.
I can always see the popup since clicking the button.

I have tested it in two PC(windows 7 and 10) with newest chrome, firefox, IE. But none of them worked.

Maybe I am not understanding what window.blur() mean?

P.S window.focus() works well in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers generally ignore `window.blur()`. This is recommended by [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#dom-window-blur).

> User agents [browsers] are encouraged to ignore calls to this blur() method entirely.

Comment: Thank you! I was just curious and downloaded an old version of firefox. It is working in old firefox v29 for example.